# how to create new box(row) inside existing column apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new to Apache POI. I have a requirement where i am writing json data to excel. In one case in a particular cell I have to create thin border rows as show in image and need to insert data(Abc,pqr...). How to achieve this using apace POI.

I am creating dynamic row based on JSON data. [image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for getting other people to write the code for you. Have a look at https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html for sample code and there are plenty of existing stackoverflow questions relating to POI and how to do things like add borders.

Comment: What your picture shows is not one row but three rows having one column merged over the three rows. So [Sheet.addMergedRegion](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#addMergedRegion-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-) needs to be used. How exactly? Well this only can be answered having a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So please show a such.

Comment: @PJFanning Ohh .I was not aware of that this website is for entertainment purpose. Thank you for remind me anyway.